# Can't create postgres database with doctrine in symfony 4.4

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4.4 with PHP 7.2 and postgres 11

I have enabled extension=pdo_pgsql and extension=pgsql in file php.ini (/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini

And then, I have restarted PHP and Nginx server.

I have added this line in .env file in the Symfony application directory

```
DATABASE_URL=pgsql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=5.7
```

When I tried to create the database by running this command

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I got following errors

```
In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 79:
An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
In PDOConnection.php line 31:
could not find driver
In PDOConnection.php line 27:
could not find driver
```

Comment: Did you check `php.ini`? `php_pdo_pgsql` is enabled?

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I got the issue because I didn't install the postgresql driver for pdo. I just did it by running sudo apt install php7.2-pgsql and the issue was resolved